# R: given a list of matrices, determine which ones have a specified value in a specific element

Tags: r

I have a list L of length k whose elements are matrices of equal dimension n x m. Suppose I want to know which of the matrices in the list satisfy the condition M[i,j]==1.

Obviously,

```
grep(1, L)
```

will not work as it will return all instances of 1 in the matrices, rather than just those where 1 occurs in position i,j. Is there any way to do this other than using a for loop and checking each matrix individually?

As a simple example, if I have a list of three matrices:

```
m1 = rbind(c(0,0,0),c(0,0,0),c(1,1,1)
m2 = rbind(c(1,1,1),c(1,0,0),c(0,0,0)
m3 = rbind(c(0,0,0),c(0,1,0),c(1,1,1)
mlist = list(m1,m2,m3)
```

I would like to find for which matrix/matrices in mlist M[2,2]=1, the correct output would be 3, since the third matrix in the list satisfies this condition.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Maybe `sapply(L, \`[\`, 2, 4)==1)` where `i=2 and `j=4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a reproducible example. We create a list of three 3 x 3 matrices called `L` which are filled with zeros. We define `i = 2` and `j = 3`, and put a 1 at the `i, j` index of our third matrix.

```r
m <- matrix(0, 3, 3)
L <- list(m, m, m)
i <- 2
j <- 3
L[[3]][i, j] <- 1

L
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    1
#> [3,]    0    0    0
```

Now to answer the question, we want an expression that finds which of the three matrices has a 1 at position `i, j`. To get this, we can do:

```
which(sapply(L, function(x) x[i, j] == 1))
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>